# Moodle Home Page with Plain Text Only, no Theme

Tags: moodle

I have just finished my Moodle instalation, through command line, using SSH. It went smootly, without any errors, but now I face something I feel like its  a huge problem.
My moodle is using no theme, its plain text.
[image: Moodle Home Page in Plain Text]

Any clues on how can I solve it?

Comment: Does the "Network" panel of the developer tools (press F12) in the browser show any problem downloading the CSS file(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem, so I post it here expecting it can be usefull for others:

Simply, **deactivate 'slash arguments'** from **Site Admin > Server > HTTP**.

Thanks for your help Andrew, but it wasn't a CSS related problem.